# Identify if power state change is caused by user or by power policy

Tags: python, windows, winapi, windows-services

I am writing a windows service in Python and this service needs to know, when a power state event occurs, what caused it. This could be the user or a power policy.
Right now, I successfully detect the events using WM_POWERBROADCAST, but I did not find any documentation about a way to achieve my goal.

Here is my current lead:
When a user turns of the computer manually, the user does necessarily input data. In user space this can be detected with [GetLastInputInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646302(v=vs.85).aspx) function. So, when a power event occurs, and if the last user input is recent, the power change was caused by the user. This does not work in a service that executes on session 0, which is a problem. I may use the [CreateProcessAsUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429(v=vs.85).aspx) function, but i'd like to avoid it.

Is there a proper way to detect if the suspend / shutdown messages are consequence of a power policy in a windows service ?

UPDATE: I tried GetLastInputInfo and it actually does not work when the user uses the power button (at least not on my computer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using CallNtPowerInformation:

```
class SYSTEM_POWER_INFORMATION(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
            ("MaxIdlenessAllowed", c_ulong),
            ("Idleness", c_ulong),
            ("TimeRemaining", c_ulong),
            ("CoolingMode", c_ubyte)
            ]

call_nt_power_information = windll.powrprof.CallNtPowerInformation
call_nt_power_information.restype = c_uint

def get_idle_timer():
    # Get the time remaining before idle
    info = SYSTEM_POWER_INFORMATION()
    r = call_nt_power_information(SystemPowerInformation, None, 0, pointer(info), sizeof(SYSTEM_POWER_INFORMATION))
    if r != 0:
        raise Exception("Call to CallNtPowerInformation failed with code " + r)

return info.TimeRemaining
```

If the power event occurs when the system is considered as idle by windows, i assume it has been initiated by a power scheme. Of course this is not ideal but works in most cases. I would still be interested in finding a better way but it seems there isn't.